# Cannot uninstall ansible with pip or brew on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, terminal, homebrew, pip, ansible

I cannot remove ansible from my machine.

If I run:

```
which ansible
/usr/local/bin/ansible
```

and

```
ansible --version                                                                          
ansible 2.7.0
  config file = /Users/josephroberts/.ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/Users/josephroberts/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.9.12 (main, Mar 26 2022, 15:52:10) [Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)]
```

Then I can clearly see it's installed and functioning on my machine.

Yet I can't seem to uninstall it? What's going on here?

```
pip uninstall ansible
WARNING: Skipping ansible as it is not installed.
```

```
pip3 uninstall ansible 
WARNING: Skipping ansible as it is not installed.
```

```
brew uninstall ansible 
Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/ansible
```

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered the same problem. I got the newer version by install without uninstall.

```
sudo -H pip3 install ansible
```